# log4net strange file name behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, log4net

I have an ASP.Net application using log4net, I like to have a daily log file, so my config looks like:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="log\log_%property{log4net:HostName}_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="7" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] (%logger)(%thread) %message %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Sometime, there are strange naming pattern file appear, it looks no reason (at least not due to maximum file-size), what's going wrong ?

[image]

Comment: I would have to check my notes from my log4net integration but I believe this problem happens when using rolling style date combined with maximum file size. Try commenting out the file size and see if the issue still occurs. Will try to post back later once i find my notes on the subject. It could also be due to your date pattern containing the fil extension but I'm not sure about the options available there.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible problems that your application identity (app pool identity) does not have enough permissions for the `log` folder. Try to change application identity for more powerful user or give to it more permission (full control for sure).

Another possible reason that your first log file `log_smv-prod-app07_20160907.txt` is locked by another process (you can find it using [procmon.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). So log4net can not write to it and creates new log file `log_smv-prod-app07_20160907.txt20160907.txt`. Try to figure out who locks it and I hope you'll find solution.

Comment: The application pool got admin right already, and it can't explains why it happen sometime only...